# IntelliJ IDEA debug enter method multiple times

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, dynamic-proxy

When debugging the following code:

```
public class MyProxy {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Consumer f = (Consumer) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                Consumer.class.getClassLoader(),
                new Class[] { Consumer.class },
                new Handler(new ConsumerImpl())
        );

        f.consume("Hello");   // set breakpoint here
        System.out.println("done");
    }
}

interface Consumer {
    void consume(String s);
}

class ConsumerImpl implements Consumer {
    public void consume(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

class Handler implements InvocationHandler {
    private final Consumer original;
    public Handler(Consumer original) {
        this.original = original;
    }
    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)
            throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException,
            InvocationTargetException {
        System.out.println("BEFORE");
        method.invoke(original, args);
        System.out.println("AFTER");
        return null;
    }
}
```

The output is :

```
BEFORE
AFTER
BEFORE
AFTER
BEFORE
BEFORE
AFTER
Hello
BEFORE
AFTER
AFTER
BEFORE
AFTER
BEFORE
AFTER
BEFORE
AFTER
BEFORE
AFTER
done
BEFORE
AFTER
```

When the debugger pause at the breakpoint line, the output already have two lines, as I step into the `invoke` method, the output is like shown. It's like the debugger is entering the `invoke` method every step I make. Because if I don't step into the method, the output is :

```
BEFORE
AFTER
BEFORE
Hello
AFTER
BEFORE
AFTER
done
BEFORE
AFTER
```

If I run the code, output is as expected.

```
BEFORE
Hello
AFTER
done
```

Is it a bug of debugger or I do something wrong?

Env: Windows 64, Intellij IDEA, JDK8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a bug in IDEA. if you try to debug this without any breakpoints you may get the same result as you expected.
But if you put some breakpoint, IDEA will try to call the toString() method , then hashCode() method of the variables that it can evaluate.

ultimately for all methods , it will call your InvocationHandler implementation (not only for the "consume" method, you can print the method.getName() to make sure this in the invocation handler implementation).

Comment: Do I understand this right: 1.  when debugging, every move I make, the debugger will re-evaluate every variable (by calling `toString()` and `hashCode()`) in scope to refresh its value.  2. When step-by-step in the `invoke` method, `this` is evaluated, causing the same effect as evaluating `f` in the `main()` .

Comment: I tested with `method.getName()` , just `toString()` is called to evaluate, no `hashCode()`.

Comment: yes, in your case it is only toString() method. first paragraph of my answer just address about the generic case, if it is a normal class (if you haven't overridden the toString()) then hashCode method will be executed through the toString() method. i think my answer is somewhat unclear about hasCode method.

Comment: @hunter could you please explain it in more detail by giving a detailed example. In my Grails controller i have a "show(id)" method which is calling 3 times in debug mode when my method have a breakpoint. And without breakpoint it is working fine in debug mode.I want to know its reason.